# HTML form to Javascript variables, not assigning

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate wages earned by 3 employees. I have the hours input for each employee with a form. I don't know how to assign multiple functions to one button so I have two buttons with one function each.

It seems like the variables "hours1, hours2, hours3" are not being assigned the values from the form.

I've tried several different ways to assign the form input to the values but I can't get it to work. I always get "Employee 1 worked **undefined** hours and earned **NaN** wages." for all my answer variables.

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Wage Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var hours1, hours2, hours3; 

var wages1 = (hours1 * wages) + ((hours1 % 40) * (wages *1.5)); 

var wages2 = (hours2 * wages) + ((hours2 % 40) * (wages *1.5));

var wages3 = (hours3 * wages) + ((hours3 % 40) * (wages *1.5));

var wages = 12;

var answer1 = "Employee 1 worked " + hours1 + " hours and earned " + wages1    + " wages.";

var answer2 = "Employee 2 worked " + hours2 + " hours and earned " + wages2 + " wages.";

var answer3 = "Employee 3 worked " + hours3 + " hours and earned " + wages3 + " wages.";


// function used to set the value input by user to variables
function setValue() {
//document.forms["myForm"]["hours1"].value;
var hours1 = document.getElementByName("hrs1")[0].value;
//document.forms["myForm"]["hours2"].value;
document.getElementById('hrs2').value = hours2;
//document.forms["myForm"]["hours3"].value;
document.getElementById('hrs3').value = hours3;
//return hours1, hours2, hours3;

}
// function that was to be used as a button for displaying the results
function displayResults() {

document.writeln(answer1);
document.writeln(answer2);
document.writeln(answer3);


}


</script>
<!-- Form to make user input and presentation much nicer -->
<form name="myForm">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Hours Employees worked:</legend>
    Employee 1:<br>

    <input id="hrs1" type="text" name="hours1"> <br>

    Employee 2:<br>

    <input id="hrs2" type="text" name="hours2"> <br>

    Employee 3:<br>

    <input id="hrs3" type="text" name="hours3"> <br>

    <input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="setValue()">


</fieldset>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="displayResults()">click</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to do, but I think that `getElementByName` is actually `getElementsByName`. Notice the plural on "elements"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    function setAndCalculateValue() {;
      var hours1, hours2, hours3, wages1, wages2, wages3, answer1, answer2, answer3;
      var wages = 12;

      hours1 = document.getElementById("hrs1").value || 0;
      hours2 = document.getElementById('hrs2').value || 0;
      hours3 = document.getElementById('hrs3').value || 0;

      wages1 = (hours1 * wages) + ((hours1 % 40) * (wages * 1.5));
      wages2 = (hours2 * wages) + ((hours2 % 40) * (wages * 1.5));
      wages3 = (hours3 * wages) + ((hours3 % 40) * (wages * 1.5));

      answer1 = "Employee 1 worked " + hours1 + " hours and earned " + wages1 + " wages.";
      answer2 = "Employee 2 worked " + hours2 + " hours and earned " + wages2 + " wages.";
      answer3 = "Employee 3 worked " + hours3 + " hours and earned " + wages3 + " wages.";
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = answer1 + "<br/ > " + answer2 + " <br /> " + answer3;


    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Wage Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- Form to make user input and presentation much nicer -->
  <form name="myForm">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Hours Employees worked:</legend>
      Employee 1:
      <br>

      <input id="hrs1" type="text" name="hours1">
      <br>Employee 2:
      <br>

      <input id="hrs2" type="text" name="hours2">
      <br>Employee 3:
      <br>

      <input id="hrs3" type="text" name="hours3">
      <br>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <input type="button" value="calc and show result" onclick="setAndCalculateValue();" />
  <br>

  <div id="result">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Since the calculation for the wages are done as soon as the document loads, it is set to NaN and hours1 to undefined.

> var wages1 = (hours1 * wages) + ((hours1 % 40) * (wages *1.5));

At this point hours1 and wages, both are undefined hence wages1 is NaN

You should calculate everything inside the a function and call it from displayResults().

I have added a working example, with some minor changes like - avoid use of global vars.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 0):

put the script block in the bottom, then your html form will exists when your script runs.

every element will be read from left to the right, top to bottom. when your javascript code runs, the html inputs does not exists yet.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `answer1`, `answer2`, and `answer3` when the code is first run, and do not reassign them in the `setValue` function. One possible solution is to add:

```
answer1 = "Employee 1 worked " + hours1 + " hours and earned " + wages1    + " wages.";

answer2 = "Employee 2 worked " + hours2 + " hours and earned " + wages2 + " wages.";

answer3 = "Employee 3 worked " + hours3 + " hours and earned " + wages3 + " wages.";
```

To the bottom of your `setValue` function, without `var`, since you're changing the value of some global variable.